# Why does this always return positive score? Simple code

Tags: java

I'm building simple game which places a boat on random element of array (random x and y). The goal is to guess place (this x and y). But anything I type it always return guessed.

```
 public static void main(String [] args){
        
    int[][] Board = new int[7][7];
    int kills = 0;
    
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.nextInt(7);
    int y = random.nextInt(7);
    
    int boat = Board[x][y];
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while (kills < 1){
            System.out.println("Where is the boat? Enter 2 digits");
            System.out.println(x+""+y);
            int guessX = input.nextInt();
            int guessY = input.nextInt();
            if (boat == Board[guessX][guessY]){
                kills = kills + 1;
                System.out.println("Sinked!");
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: `int boat = Board[x][y]` is going to set `boat` to zero.  Which is the value of every element of those arrays.  What value were you expecting it to have?

Comment: You don't actually put the boat anywhere in the grid...

Comment: you can simply the solution to comparing  ```if(guessX==x && guessY==y) {kills++;}``` then you don't need to use a 2 dimensional array for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the code you are initializing a Board array with default value(0 in java for int)
Then you are just comparing the value in the array at a random index generated against the user input index array value.
In this case both are zero and hence it shows a match every time.

To make it work you can compare the indices guessed against the indices randomly generated to designate the boat.

Answer (score 1):

`int boat = Board[x][y]` is going to set `boat` to zero. Which is the value of every element of those arrays.

To add a boat, you have to actually set one of the array elements to a value.

```
int boat = 1;
Board[x][y] = boat;
```

(Edit: and I'm not sure now if this is a real question or if the program is just some sort of late night typo.)